# Show that there exists a certain operator in $L(H)$ where $H$ is a separable Hilbert Space.

Tags: proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Given a separable Hilbert Space $H$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ an
>   absolutely convergent series in $H$, I need to show that there is an
>   operator $A \in L(H)$ such that $A(e_n)=f_n$, where $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an ortonormal basis in $H$ .

This is what I have done:

Considering the fact that for every $x \in H $ $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ne_n$ We define the operator $A$ as:

$$A: \hspace{0.4cm}  H \hspace{0.3cm} \longrightarrow \hspace{0.3cm} H$$
$$\hspace{1.5cm} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ne_n \longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_nf_n$$

- $A(e_n)=f_n$
- It is obvious that $A$ is linear, as $A(x+y)=A( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ne_n +  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_ne_n)=A( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n+y_n)e_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n+y_n)f_n=A(x)+A(y)$. Also $A(\alpha x)= \alpha A(x)$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now we need to show that A is bounded (i.e continuous):

We now that a separable Hilbert Space is isometrically isomorphic to $l_2$, so abussing of the notation (By identifying $H$ with $l_2$) we have:

$$ ||A(x)||_{l_2}=||\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_nf_n||_{l_2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|||f_n||_{l_2}$$

We consider the series $|x|=(|x_1|, |x_2|,...)$ and $||f||=(||f_1||_{l_2},||f_2||_{l_2},...)$. Both belong to $l_2$, as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ne_n \in l_2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ is absolutely convergent, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||f_n||_{l_2} < \infty$ and then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||f_n||_{l_2}^{2} < \infty$ (Because $a^2 \leq a$ for $a \in [0,1]$ and the sequence $(||f_n||)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to 0$ ).

We can now consider Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for $l_2$ so that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|||f_n||_{l_2} \leq ||x||_{l_2} ||(||f||)||_{l_2}$$

That is,

$$ ||A(x)||_{l_2} \leq ||x||_{l_2} ||(||f||)||_{l_2} =C ||x||_{l_2} $$

And as we have an isometric isomorphism between $l_2$ and $H$ we have proven that:

- $A$ is bounded.

Comment: The proof seems correct, but "wrong". "Wrong" because you never _use_ the fact that $H$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2$. (When you say for example $||A(x)||_{l_2}=||\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_nf_n||_{l_2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|||f_n||_{l_2}$ you could simply say the same thing with $||.||_H$ in place of the $\ell^2$ norm.)

Comment: I have a doubt. How can you assure that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_nf_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I decided to use $l_2$ because I needed $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|||f_n||_{l_2}$ to be the scalar product in order to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @V. González Because it is bounded by a convergent series.

Comment: I didn't say $\ell_2$ is not going to come up! Yes, you use Cauchy-Schwarz in $\ell_2$ to show that that sum is finite. But _that_ use of $\ell_2$ has absolutely nothing to do with your assumption that $H=\ell_2$. If you don't assume that $H=\ell_2$ you can still use Cauchy-Schwarz in $\ell_2$ to show that $\sum |x_n|\,||f_n||_H$ is finite, by exactly the same argument.

Comment: I'd probably not _mention_ $\ell_2$ even there; I'd just say $\sum|x_n|\,||f_n||_H\le(\sum|x_n|^2)^{1/2}(\sum||f_n||_H^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Btw Gonlaez has a point: You should really show that $\sum|x_n|\,||f_n||_H<\infty$ _before_ giving the definition of $A$. Given the order in which you wrote things you prove $A$ is bounded before showing that $A(x)$ even _exists_, which does't really make sense.

Comment: Okay, so I should use the fact that $|| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_nf_n ||_{H} < \infty$ first, to show that it is well defined. This is proven by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality as above. Right?

Comment: I would also like to know how to conclude from $(\sum|x_n|^2)^{1/2}(\sum||f_n||_H^2)^{1/2}$ that A is bounded, as I cannot link it with the H-norm of x.

Comment: Right. More or less. You say you should show $||\sum x_nf_n||<\infty$ first. Not _quite_ - you can't write that sum at the start because as far as we know there is no such thing as that sum. You should show $\sum||x_nf_n||<\infty$ first. (Then you've shown that $\sum x_nf_n$ exists, you can now define $A$, and you've already done what's needed to show $A$ is bounded.)

Comment: ??? If $x=\sum x_ne_n$ then $||x||_H=(\sum |x_n|^2)^{1/2}$. That's like the point to the $e_n$ being orthonormal...